# Splitting a string for "\n" without affecting "\\n" in the string in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, split

I have a string which contains new line character `\n` and a backslash character `\\` followed by an `n`.

The objective is to split the string into arrays only when a new line character `\n` is found and not when a backslash `\\` an `n` character are present `\\n`.

E.g :

```
Hi, \n How are \\n you?\n I am great!
```

Result :

```
["Hi, ", " How are \\n you?", " I am great!"]
```

By using only `split("\n")`, you will get

```
["Hi, ", " How are \", " you?", " I am great!"]
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: `split("\n")` [yields the expected](https://ideone.com/PB7wGs) `["Hi, ", "How are \\n you?", "I am great!"]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the regex as follow:

```js
//["Hi, ", " How are \\n you?", " I am great!"]
console.log("Hi, \n How are \\n you?\n I am great!".split(/\n/g))
```